# how to stop resizing embedded google map?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

here is my full code of contact form where cards and google map are side by side.but when I resizing the window google map size automatically reduce.I try some solutions that are in already posted here but does not any one work for me.Please help me out.how to solve this issue and fixed google map in same size? can any one help me?

Thanks in advance :)

```css
.contact .iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;

}
.contact .iframe-container > *{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
   margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.contact #heading
{
 
}
.contact .card {
 
  display: inline-block;
 margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
 
}
.contact .card-4 , .card-5 ,.card-6 {
  
  height: 80px;
   width: 250px;
}
.contact .container
{
 
 margin:0px;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--jQuery library--> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="contact">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card card-4"><p>card 1</p></div>
<div class="card card-5"><p>card 2 </p></div>  
<div class="card card-6"><p>card 3</p></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6" id="heading">
 <div class="iframe-container">
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d241316.6433229747!2d72.74109780863925!3d19.082522323775425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3be7c6306644edc1%3A0x5da4ed8f8d648c69!2sMumbai%2C+Maharashtra!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1554386783773!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your css, everything that has to do with iframe is set to a % width, so of course when you resize the window, the map will resize. And whatever grid system you got going most likely resizes based on window size as well which affects he map in this case

Comment: iframe-container { min-width: 400px }

Comment: @DanieleDolci thanks...but it not working..